# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) : Recent Files (MRU) menu is too abbreviated to be usable

Tags: sql-server, ssms, usability

I have problems locating the correct SQL file to edit in the **Recent Files** (sometimes called MRU) list in recent versions of SSMS (I'm using 18.5). My files have similar names or the same name and are located in different folders. This didn't used to be a problem in earlier versions of SSMS (pre-18 I think). It also seems to be inconsistent with the **Recent Projects and Solutions** menu option immediately below it in the File menu, which doesn't seem to have this limitation.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem:
[Screen shot contrasting current and previous SSMS feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfcfU.jpg) and 
[Sample of problem showing similar filenames in menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igbIX.png)

I have searched the web and am a bit surprised nobody has raised this before. 
I logged the problem here last year but no response from MS: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37368973-ssms-18-recent-files-list-too-narrow

Does anyone know a registry setting to expand the menu or have some other workaround?

Comment: Not what I was looking for, sorry @Weihui. The Recent Files feature is a productivity aid because it allows you to **select** files to open you have been working on and previously closed. In prior versions of SSMS, more of the filename/path was visible than now. So when you have files that are similarly named (or have exactly the same name but are located in another folder) it is difficult to differentiate them in the list. Please refer to the screenshot to see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that feature, @Weihui. Wouldn't it be nice if there was also a tooltip showing the full path when you hover over an entry in the Recent Files list? The point I am making is that the Recent Files shortcoming prevents it from being as useful as it once was. I don't want to have to open files to find out what they are.

Comment: I completely agree with this article.... the filenames are so shortened, the names are unreadable.  (I'm using SSMS 19.1.)   Why did they do this... and why shorten them that much.... but then leave a load of space on the right hand side...?!!  Its terrible UI.